# server is not accepting connection when client requests for connection

Tags: c, sockets

My server is not accepting the connection request sent by the client and client recieves nothing from it.when client request it my server gets down.
My code is as follows:
SERVER CODE:

```
*#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int sock,bnd,con,lis,size,clilen;
    char *msg="WELCOME!!!!!";
    struct sockaddr_in sockadd,cliadd;
    //Socket Created.....
    sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sock!=-1)
    printf("socket created");
    else
    printf("Not created");

        // defining  Address of sockets
    sockadd.sin_family=AF_INET;
    sockadd.sin_port=htons(5001);
    sockadd.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    bnd=bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *) &sockadd,sizeof(sockadd));
    if(bnd==-1)
    printf("NOT BOUND");
    else
    printf("BOUND");

    lis=listen(sock,10);
    if(lis!=-1)
    printf("listning");
    else
    printf("not listening");
    printf("\nWaiting for connection at %s port no %d\n",inet_ntoa(sockadd.sin_addr),ntohs(sockadd.sin_port));
    while(1)
    {
        clilen=sizeof(cliadd);
        con=accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *) &cliadd, &clilen);
        if(con==-1)
        printf("connected not");
        else
        printf("conneted");
        size=send(sock,msg,sizeof(msg),0);
        if(size==-1)
        printf("not sent");
        else
        printf("BYTES SENT: %d",size);
        close(con);
        sleep(2);
    }
    return(0);*
```

and Client code is :

```
    int sock,bnd,con,lis,size;
    char msg[35];
    struct sockaddr_in sockadd;
    //Socket Created.....
    sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sock!=-1)
    printf("socket created");
    else
    printf("Not created");
    //return(0);        
        // defining  Address of sockets
    sockadd.sin_family=AF_INET;
    sockadd.sin_port=htons(5001);
    sockadd.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("10.3.5.172");
    /*puts(sockadd.sin_family);
    puts(sockadd.sin_port); 
    puts(sockadd.sin_addr.s_addr);      
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &sockadd.sin_addr)<=0)
       {
         printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
            return 1;
        } */
    con=connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sockadd, sizeof(sockadd)) ;
    if(con==-1)
        {
        printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
             return 1;
        } 
    else
    printf("successful");
    size=recv(sock,msg,sizeof(msg),0);
    printf("msg recieved:%s",msg);
    printf("bytes recieved:%d",size);
}*
```

Comment: Looks OK. Can you connect from localhost ? Can you do a `tcpdump` and find out if anyone is filtering you ?

Comment: server executes and wait for connection but when client executes n requests ,Server terminates.

Comment: This code is a mess - in a few places it continues execution despite errors. Server uses a wrong socket descriptor to send. Formatting makes it hard to read...

Comment: Any output from the server? Any error message from the OS?

Comment: @kanika You should write newlines after every message you print out. Otherwise you might not see anything until the process (cleanly) terminates. That is, do e.g `printf("connected not\n");` instead of `printf("connected not\n");`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to send on the server socket!

```
  size=send(sock,msg,sizeof(msg),0); // ERROR, this is a server socket!
```

Try sending on the new connection instead:

```
  size=send(con,msg,sizeof(msg),0);
```

Comment: Thanks it has successfully executes after this